# OOP on Snake game:Confused as heck because of this IndexError List on it

Tags: python, oop

So currently. I'm making a a snake game type of game and I've run to a bit  of a problem. An IndexError, and a few other errors. been trying to understand this since for some odd reason, it works for my udemy instructor. I am very confused on the error Here's the code:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from D20_snake import Snake
import time

#setup screen, widths, and heights)
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.title("Armand's Snake game!")
#tracer function to turn animation on/off)
screen.tracer(0)
screen.textinput(title="Start!",prompt="Type Anything to Start Playing the Snake Game: ")


snake = Snake()


screen.listen()
screen.onkey(snake.up, "Up")
screen.onkey(snake.down, "Down")
screen.onkey(snake.left, "Left")
screen.onkey(snake.right, "Right")


game_is_on = True
while game_is_on:
    screen.update()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    
    snake.move()


screen.exitonclick()
```

And here's the Object I'm talking about

```
from turtle import Turtle
#Create the Snake Body and Class, starting with 3 white squares.
STARTING_POSITIONS = [(0,0),(-20,0),(-40,0)]
MOVE_DISTANCE = 20
#make segments list and snake object for snake body, that will get appended with each new body part
UP = 90
DOWN = 270
LEFT = 180
RIGHT = 0


class Snake:

   def __init__(self):
        self.segments = []
        self.head = self.segments[0]
    #snake body
   def create_snake(self):
        for position in STARTING_POSITIONS:
            new_segment = Turtle("square")
            new_segment.color("white")
            new_segment.penup()
            new_segment.goto(position)
            self.segments.append(new_segment)
   def move(self):
        for seg_num in range(len(self.segments) -1,0,-1):
            new_x = self.segments[seg_num - 1].xcor()
            new_y = self.segments[seg_num - 1].ycor()
            self.segments[seg_num].goto(new_x,new_y)
        self.head.forward(MOVE_DISTANCE)  
    #arrow key movements        
   def up(self):
        if self.head.heading() != DOWN:
            self.head.setheading(UP)
   def down(self):
        if self.head.heading() !=UP:
            self.head.setheading(DOWN)
   def left(self):
        if self.head.heading() !=RIGHT:
            self.head.setheading(LEFT)
   def right(self):
        if self.head.heading() !=LEFT:
            self.head.setheading(RIGHT)
```

And this indexerror pops up in the segment list:

```
 File "c:\Users\Armand S\Desktop\Python Files\D20 The Snake Game.py", line 16, in <module>
    snake = Snake()
  File "c:\Users\Armand S\Desktop\Python Files\D20_snake.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.head = self.segments[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't quite understand it myself, and I'm very confused. There's clearly [0] on the list but it just says indexerror.

Comment: The error means that your list index is larger than the size of the list. Since lists are 0-indexed, it attempts to get the first element in the list, but there isn't one since you just set the list to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

In your main file when you made an instance of Snake class :

```
snake = Snake()
```

it runs the `__init__` method in the Snake class
where you defined :

```
self.segments = []
```

and in the next line without appending any item to the segments list , you wrote  :

```
self.head = self.segments[0]
```

Although at this moment segments list must not be empty

to solve problem change the `__init__` method to something like this :

```
def __init__(self):
    x = 1   #or maybe something else
    self.segments = [x]
    self.head = self.segments[0]
```